# How to stop react router executing itself for universal react?

Tags: php, reactjs, react-router, universal-react

I'm trying to render Redux + Webpack in PHP. My current workflow is as simple as below.

1. Compile ES6 into js using babel
2. Use PHP V8 classes to include scripts from step #1
3. Render contents
4. Include javascripts used in #1 with script tags.

Everything works fine, except that the included script in #4 re-renders the same view since the route matches. In the route, I have the following configuration.

`<Provider store={store}>
        <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <Router history={browserHistory} children={routes} />
        </div>
      </Provider>`

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the `Router` component to register routes, but not execute them?

Comment: Maybe this article can help you https://neemzy.org/articles/routing-aware-react-server-side-rendering-on-php-with-silex-and-react-router, the author executes server-side route matching of react-router using `v8js`